# Appropriate sample size for paired t-test--forest measurement

Tags: sample-size

I am trying to conduct a paired t-test to detect if there is a difference between the mean value of a parameter calculated by another person and myself (carbon stocks of forest types) but am unsure of the appropriate sample size.  Basically I need to independently verify the exact same samples.  One sample was measured a year ago, and I need to verify if it was correct.  I know a paired t-test is the most appropriate test but do not know how to calculate the correct number of samples I need to plan on doing.  They have 114 plots where the carbon in the forest was measured.  The average carbon stocks is 640 tons per hectare.  How many of the 114 plots should I plan on having to visit to confirm (alpha 0.05, Power 0.8) the 650 value is correct.  The original sampling had a standard deviation of 462. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to know what difference you would like to be able to detect. 
Second, If I understand your problem, it will be difficult to verify the 640 value (or is it 650?). The standard deviation is very large so you would have to be satisfied with a very large detectable difference. If 462 is in fact the *variance*, and not the standard deviation, then you will need to visit only 22 sites to detect a difference of 15 tons/hectare.